# SQL: How to extract previous month starting at beginning of month

Tags: oracle

I have the below where clause that extracts the previous three month but I would like to see the previous three months starting with the first of the month.

```
AND A.START_DT > add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TRUNC` function `fmt` parameter

`select TRUNC(TO_DATE('27/10/92','DD/MM/YY'), 'MONTH') from dual`

Comment: I'm  not using a hard coded date, see example provided.

Comment: It's just example to show you that it works. You can write your own code.

Comment: This worked for my example. AND TRUNC(A.START_DT, 'MONTH') > add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -3)